# How to read sql server insert/update into value with mybatis?

Tags: mybatis, temporal-tables

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a SQL Sever temporal table's SYSSTARTTIME field with myBatis and can't figure it out. I had something like this:

```
<insert id="insertVersionedTableData" parameterType="com.me.dao.vo.DataVO">
    <selectKey keyProperty="systemStartTm" resultType="java.util.Date" order="AFTER">
        SELECT sysstarttm FROM @MyTableVar;
    </selectKey>
    DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (sysstarttm datetime);
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.versioned_table (id, first_name, last_name)
    OUTPUT inserted.system_start_tm into @MyTableVar
    VALUES (#{id}, #{firstName}, #{lastName});
</insert>
```

When I run this though I can see the insert in the console logging but it then throws an exception saying that @MyTableVar must be declared so it's like the table variable goes out of scope after the insert and the  tag runs just like a regular SELECT

I've tried the generated keys functionality too but myBatis expects the key to be the first field in the table which my autogenerated SYSTEMSTARTTIME is not.